# Using a function in another class in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, class

So I have this code here, and i want to use validate result (false) in another class, how do i do it? i cant get access to it

```
class Login extends Base {

    constructor(propertyValues) {
        super(propertyValues);
    }

    validate {
        var usernamed = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var passworded = document.getElementById("password").value;
        if (usernamed == "abc" && passworded == "123") {
            alert("Login successfully");
            window.location = "http://localhost:3000/tasksMenu"; // Redirecting to other page.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where you use "validate result" ?

Comment: For method, validate should be in this format `validate(){}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make validate static as it doesn't do anything with the class' `this` and seems to be pretty, well, static. Second, I wouldn't put the redirection logic in a validate function but handle the redirection in the function that later calls the validation. So just make `validate()` return true or false, and handle the rest from where you call it:

```
class Login extends Base {

    constructor(propertyValues) {
        super(propertyValues);
    }

    static validate() {
        let usernamed = document.getElementById("username").value;
        let passworded = document.getElementById("password").value;
        return usernamed == "abc" && passworded == "123";
    }
}

class Foo {
    bar() {
        if (Login.validate()) {
            alert("success");
            // redirect to your success page
        } else {
            alert("wrong credentials");
            // redirect to your error page
        }
    }
}

new Foo().bar();
```

---

Sidenote:

As you've tagged this with html and javascript, I assume you are writing a front-end login system? If so, don't do this! Everything in the front-end can be read by everyone using your site; this includes the password and username you check against. **Login is made on the backend**!!!

Answer (score 0):

First you have syntax error in your class.You should define your validate function as :

```
validate() {
//...
}
```

You can have access to this function in another class provided it is loaded after this class.For example you can access it like following :

```
class other {
    access() {
        var login = new Login("pass your property values");
        console.log(login.validate());
    }
}
new other().access();
```